# Separator's cell different height

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, scroll, cell, separator

I have a problem with all my tableview and its separator's cell. Randomly one separator cell (sometimes more than one) is higher than the others and I don´t know why. I tried with setSeparatorColor and also adding a custom view at the end of every cell but is always the same effect. Besides, when I scrolling the tableview this occurs in other cells.

You can see pics related in this album https://i.stack.imgur.com/h67pZ.jpg. First pic is my desired situation, second pic is how the view is showed initially and last pic is an example of scrolling.